# I have error while running tests: 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured.'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, error-handling, django-testing

I am writing tests for my DjangoRestFramework application and get the error while running the tests. Trying to solve it for a long period of time but unsuccessfully Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/Загрузки/pycharm-2023.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 38, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 150, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 161, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/core/account/tests/test_models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 139, in <module>
    class APIRequestFactory(DjangoRequestFactory):
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 140, in APIRequestFactory
    renderer_classes_list = api_settings.TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 218, in __getattr__
    val = self.user_settings[attr]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 209, in user_settings
    self._user_settings = getattr(settings, 'REST_FRAMEWORK', {})
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/rroxxxsii/PycharmProjects/django_rest_shop/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite
```

Here is file with test if needed:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from account.models import User


class TestUserCreate(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        pass

    def test_create_superuser_with_correct_data(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser(email='superuser@gmail.com', first_name='super',
                                      second_name='user', password='superuser')
```

WSGI file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Settings configuration for REST_FRAMEWORK:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

I would be very glad if someone finds the reason of the issue and help to solve it.

I tried to run the test and I did not supposed to run into the error that occured somewhere in project settings, as I suppose.